# How to support Aggregations query using NativeQuery

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

How to support Aggregations query using NativeQuery in Spring Data Elasticsearch 5.x and new client, I've attached the existing implementation we used in 4.x

```
protected <T> SearchHits searchHitsForAggregation(QueryBuilder queryBuilder,
        AbstractAggregationBuilder<?> aggregationBuilders, Pageable pageable) {
    NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withSearchType(SearchType.DEFAULT)
            .withQuery(queryBuilder).withAggregations(aggregationBuilders);

    if (pageable == null) {
        searchQueryBuilder.withMaxResults(0);
    }
    else {
        searchQueryBuilder.withPageable(pageable);
    }

    NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = searchQueryBuilder.build();
    return operations.search(searchQuery, indexClass(), indexCoordinates());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the corresponding method from the `NativeQueryBuilder`:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/client/elc/NativeQueryBuilder.html#withAggregation(java.lang.String,co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.aggregations.Aggregation)

Comment: We did notice the above method earlier, but we would like to use the existing interface which is passing a List (say AbstractAggregationBuilder<?> aggregationBuilders), it doesn't seem to have direct compatibility

Comment: The classes from the new elasticsearch-java library are not compatible with the old one, you cannot reuse these AggregationBuilders anymore.